# Как правильно написать: "произвести подготовку прибора к проведению измерений" или "провести подготовку прибора..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать: "произвести подготовку прибора к проведению измерений" или "провести подготовку прибора..."

Answer (score 1):

Допустимы оба варианта и «произвести», и «провести», поскольку у этих слов есть общий синоним - «выполнить».
Однако, технические тексты украшает точность изложения, а не вставка очевидно лишних слов. Поэтому правильным будет самый простой из возможных вариантов - «подготовить прибор к измерениям».